# Duda con DOM en Java

Tags: java, dom

estoy intentando hacer una lectura de un fichero XML desde java con DOM lo que pasa es que yo quiero modificar el método recorrerRamaDomSecuencial para que muestre la información de un empleado por su nombre y no sé cómo hacerlo. Lo tengo hecho para que lea todo el documento XML en orden pero no sé como seria para muestre la información por su nombre. Es decir por la etiqueta nombre.

```
Fichero xml: empleados.xml
<listado>
<<empleado id="1">
<dni>74857485F</dni>
<nombre>Mateo</nombre>
<apellido>Ros</apellido>
<email>mateo.ros@aaa</email>
<telefono>65498</telefono>
<direccion/>
<fecha_nacimiento/>
</empleado>
<empleado id="2">
<dni>12455L</dni>
<nombre>Marta</nombre>
<apellido>Sanz</apellido>
<email>m.sanz@aaaa</email>
<telefono>654986</telefono>
<direccion/>
<fecha_nacimiento/>
</empleado>

Código JAVA:

public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document documento = builder.parse(new File("empleados.xml"));


recorrerRamaDom(documento);

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

}

public static void recorrerRamaDom(Node nodo) {

if (nodo != null) {

System.out.println(nodo.getNodeName() + ": " + nodo.getNodeValue());

NodeList hijos = nodo.getChildNodes();

for (int i = 0; i < hijos.getLength(); i++) {

Node nodoNieto = hijos.item(i);

recorrerRamaDom(nodoNieto);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Hola, muestra el código de recorrerRamaDom, y si pasas los datos a una lista y esa es al que ordenas?.

Comment: Hola, el método recorrerRamaDom está en la parte de abajo del código. Muchas gracias de todos modos.